# Disable cache ONLY in header

Tags: php, wordpress, caching

I know this is a wide question, but I'd like to know which approach you take for achieving this.

Currently I am developing a project which is cached with WP Super Cache plugin. In the header (which is displayed, of course, in every page), there's a message that says "Hello 'nameoftheloggeduser'". I don't want to cache this part of the code, so as the message changes if you log out or if you log in with another account.

```
<ul id="user-menu" class="menu">
    <?php if ($up->current_user->ID == 0) : ?>
       <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($up->signup_page) ?>">Sign 
       Up</a></li>
       <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($up->profile_page) ?>">Log 
       In</a></li>
       <?php else : ?>
       <li><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($up->profile_page) ?>">Hello, <? 
       = $up->current_user_data->first_name ?></a></li>
       <?php endif; ?></ul>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [WP Super Cache](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-cache/), static html pages are only served to users who are not logged in so I don't think you have anything to worry about.

Comment: It says "99% of visitors will be served html static files". Moreover, I have tried it and the problem actually exists. I just would like to know if there's a function to uncache certain part of the code (maybe somebody can write one manually)

Comment: Okay cool. Well the answer is on that link anyway. Scroll down to "How do I make certain parts of the page stay dynamic?"

Comment: It just says "You can use Javascript to draw the part of the page you want to keep dynamic". What does that mean? How do I procceed?

Comment: Well one idea might be to use a javascript AJAX call to fetch the username rather than using PHP. Some info on using AJAX with WordPress... https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins